# Do companies often re-run background checks / drug tests when converting from contractor?

Tags: recruitment, human-resources

Do companies often re-run background checks / drug tests when converting from contractor to w2 in house employee?

How common is this practice?

Comment: Step 1: get a coin, decide heads or tails...

Comment: This might really depend on the industry you're in and the type of job you have. If you operate heavy machinery or perform a job that might endanger others, then expect to have more frequent tests. As it stands, your question is super difficult to answer since we don't know they type of job you have.

Comment: Depends on the company. Some don't do it at all, some do it even when you are already employed with them. If they have a policy against drugs, assume that you will be tested and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  At companies that have mandatory drug testing, they tend to do it as a fixed part of the onboarding process and don’t skip it because you were a contractor, or worked there before, or have a relative that works there, or...

Even if it is not strictly mandated and they don’t do routine recurring testing, it’s usually simplest for them to follow the generic checklist so that’s the most common case.

Comment: Yes, it's mandatory for some industries regardless

Answer (score 1):

*"Oh hell yeah, at this point in my [koff, koff ...] career, I could tell you plenty of stories(!)"* about companies who **didn't** do background checks *and* drug tests when they should have.  (No, I'm not going to repeat them now.  But, "you really don't want to know.")  Companies have learned the very-hard way to conduct these tests at *every* legal opportunity.

"Of course, of course, *you're* clean."  But you're not the one they're looking for – and may you never actually encounter anyone they *do* want to find.  (As I unfortunately have, in both cases.)  So, "just smile and play along."